# MongoDB:: How to rewrite aggregation function with map-reduce in python

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, mapreduce, jupyter-lab

I need help with writing function with map-reduce. I have such collection and aggregation function with it:

```
import pymongo

db_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

current_db = db_client["pyloungedb"] 

collection2 = current_db["Abonement bought"]

abonement_bought = [
    {'ID': 1000,'client_id': 2 , 'price': 10,'client': 'Petras Petraitis','start_date': '2022.10.14','end_date': '2022.10.14'},
    {'ID': 1000, 'client_id': 1, 'price': 30,'client': 'Jonas Jonaitis','start_date': '2021.09.14','end_date': '2022.10.14'},
    {'ID': 1002, 'client_id': 3, 'price': 300,'client': 'Monika Mokaite','start_date': '2020.10.14','end_date': '2021.10.14'}
]

ins_result = collection2.insert_many(abonement_bought)  
print(ins_result.inserted_ids)

agg_result= collection2.aggregate( 
    [{ 
    "$group" :{
        "_id" : "$ID",
        "Total" : {"$sum" : 1},
        "revenue":{"$sum" : "$price"}}}
    
        
    ]) 
for i in agg_result: 
    print(i)
```

I have to rewrite this with map-reduce function. Note: var doesn't work, so I have a code, which should work, just I get empty result after printing it

```
def mapReduce():
    mapf = "function(){emit(this.$ID, this.$price)}"
    reducef = "function(k, v) { return Array.sum(v) }" 
    result = current_db.command(
        'mapReduce',  
        'collection2',  
        map=mapf,  
        reduce=reducef,  
        out={'inline': 1})

    print(result)

mapReduce()
```

Output:
{'results': [], 'ok': 1.0}

Using JupyterLab Python

Comment: May I ask what the motivation for this change is? Is `current_db` in the second code snippet still pointing to a MongoDB cluster (using the deprecated [mapReduce command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/))? The guidance from the vendor is to do the exact opposite, go from that command to aggregation ([reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/map-reduce-to-aggregation-pipeline/)).

Comment: It is not a motivation from my side, it is exercise I need to complete, thus unfortunately I can't do the exact opposite and go back to aggregation as You suggest.